# How can a 2 handed dagger stun lock a havel monster to death?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was just chilling and collecting weapons on my completionist account. I was maximum soul level in the lower brightstone cove when an arbiter spirit invaded me. He was cosplaying hidie knight, and rolled around non stop a dozen times. Then when I was in a corner, he took his dagger, and hit me over a dozen times with it, each hit doing 200-300 damage. I was wearing some of the best armor in the game, with total defenses being around 1,200 in each stat. with 2,600 HP. So is this actually possible? or was he hacking with infinite stamina and using mundane dagger with all 99 stats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dagger is incredibly broken in this sense, having an incredibly high poise-damage range and *incredible* crit damage. So in short, no, he wasn't hacking.

The long story is there are some mechanics and items that can help boost the output of weapons to achieve this effect:

- Imbuing (Raw/Mundane)

Imbuing a weapon with Raw will reduce the scaling a weapon has (in the case of a Dagger, the scaling drops from STR/DEX E/B to E/E), with the trade-off for a higher base damage.

On the other hand, Mundane changes your scaling to scale off your lowest stat(s) (all stats are taken into account) so a way to achieve insane damage levels is to keep all your stat levels even (eg 20).

- Rings

There are several rings in the game that can increase the damage output of your weapon, and even the amount of poise damage (how easy it is to stagger someone). The two that come to mind are the Ring of Blades (+2 increases your physical attack by 50) and the Stone Ring which reduces enemy poise; essentially making the enemy (you) easier to stun-lock. The Red Tearstone Ring increases your base damage output by 20% when your health drops below 30%

- Equipment

Some equipment can also affect damage output as well. The Engraved Gauntlets (thanks for reminding me GEnGEr) give a chance around a 5-15% chance (still need to figure that one out) to make a single attack critical (1.5x damage).

Comment: Don't forget about the "Engraved Gauntlets" that can also boost the Crit chance.